# SAML response in url is too long

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, aws-api-gateway

I'm following a fantastic article [SAML for Your Serverless JavaScript Application](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/saml-for-your-serverless-javascript-application-part-i/) that is for a web app to provide SSO with AWS Cognito using a SAML reponse from a given IdP. 
Here's the diagram for the architecture: [image: architecture]

So my issue is at the end when API-G redirects back to my site. I can see in the chrome/firefox dev tools that the 302 redirect works and has the correct url and the saml response in the url, but then the page fails to load. Chrome shows 'canceled' and firefox doesn't do anything with it.

I did notice that the total url length is about 8500 characters and if I make it around 7500 characters or less then it works, but larger than about 7500, then it breaks.

So why did it work for whoever wrote the article, but I can't get it? The error might be different than what I think it is, it just seems to be the length of the url.

Locally I'm running an Angular 4 app with `ng serve`, and the final app will be a single page application hosted out of an S3 bucket.

Comment: What are you modifying to get the URL down from 8500 characters to 7500? What service is the 301 redirecting to exactly?

Comment: To I just deleted characters off the SAML response directly. The 302 comes from AWS API-G/Lambda and the redirect is a GET to the S3 bucket that's hosting the web app (since it's a SPA and a serverless setup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using AWS CloudFront with your S3 bucket then there is a 8,192 byte URL limit which appears to be the cause of the issue.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-limits.html

A SAML Response can be different lengths for different reasons. Some reasons could be:

- Included signing public certificate (and its variables)
- Attribute statement (user information that is included with the assertion)

So perhaps the author was producing SAML Responses that resulted in a smaller redirect URL.

Additionally, there seems to be nothing in the RFC that dictates a limit on URI length, so their server/browser may be set up differently to you.

Comment: I'll take that as an answer for now. Yeah, I wasn't able to get exactly the issue, but it does seem like we just have more stuff added to the SAML making it larger. Also I'll have to tack on lots of info about the roles the person can assume in AWS, so I just went a different route for now.

As for the limit on the URI length, that's why I was curious, in my case I should be set up exactly the same as the blog I was following, which is just a simple SPA hosted in S3 (serverless setup). I'm guessing that S3 has an issue when a GET comes along with 7500+ characters

Comment: Are you using CloudFront to access your S3 bucket? If so, I think you're on the right track. CloudFront has a 8,192 byte URL limit, and that looks like it's in the realm of what you're working with there.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-limits.html

Comment: THAT, could you add that as an actual answer or to your answer. Because that's it, I am using cloudfront. That's why then, that it isn't working.

Comment: Updated as requested